# Merge adapter data using AsyncQueryHandler or AsycTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider, android-adapter

I have a `RecyclerView` with a cursor adapter. For each item loaded from the cursor I will need to load additional data from an external `ContentProvider` (not mine).

I am considering starting either an `AsyncQueryHandler` or an `AsyncTask` from my adapters `onBindViewHolder()`. Which is the better choice and why?

Or is this approach just a bad idea? Is there a better solution for merging data from disparate sources?

Answer (score 1):

What I'd advise is looking in to RxJava.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/The-RxJava-Android-Module

Why? Well the only downfall is the learning curve. However, RxJava has a nice way of handling all of the things that AsyncTasks suck at. Neither of the options are technically *bad*, but there is a lot more work you will have to do to make sure it actually works inside your lifecycle and multiple conditions that I frankly think isn't worth the effort, especially since RxJava makes it so much easier.

For your convenience, here is something to get you going on converting an AsyncTask to an Rx.Observable. After you get the hang of it, you'll never use an AsyncTask again!

http://blog.stablekernel.com/replace-asynctask-asynctaskloader-rx-observable-rxjava-android-patterns/

Comment: Thanks, I was starting to think this could be a problem for Rx. Using `map` might be useful. I have one stream and a function (the second query) that can be mapped over each element in the stream. Not sure if this is the best way.